# ibm-mobilefirst-starter container for Bluemix - adding new http adapter not working

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-console

I created **ibm-mobilefirst-starter:latest** container in bluemix. And I am able to access the MFS console.I can see MobileFirstStarter run time its working fine. Now I **uploaded new .wlapp  and one http .adapter** file into MFS console and they are visible in Console. When I try to access the Adapter from Common Resources I am getting Error :

*[http://134.168.31.10:9080/MobileFirstStarter/authorization/v1/clients/preview] failure. state: 404, response: The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.*

*Client registration failed with error: {"responseHeaders":{"Date":"Tue, 01 Mar 2016 12:35:44 GMT","Connection":"Close","X-Powered-By":"Servlet/3.0","Content-Length":"0","Content-Language":"en-US"},"status":404,"responseText":"","errorCode":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","errorMsg":"The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.","invocationContext":null}*

[image]

I tried with **Android environment and tested in device**. Couldn't see any response from adapter.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no preview available from the console in non-development environments (i.e. MobileFirst Studio plug-in for Eclipse).

It is unclear from your question if only the preview failing or also from a device/emulator.

Comment: Later I tested the same from Android Device. by installing APK and Deploying Android Environment to  Console. Then also I couldn't get Response from adapter. I tested the Connectvity to server by testing remote disable and Notify they are working fine. No issue with Connectvity between Device and Console

Comment: Then it looks like your adapter is not pointing to the right place?

Comment: Adapter is just returning hard coded json object. No Rest API involved. And No Security test.

Comment: may be your suggestion was rite about adapter not pointing to right place. Now I replaced the hard coded json object with cloudant URL. Now Adapter is working. Thanks